# How can I remove the sound indicator from the top menu of the gnome-shell?

Tags: gnome-shell, manjaro

[image]

I am using manjaro linux with gnome shell 3.24.3. There is a sound indicator in top menu. How can I remove it ? I searched couple of hours, but I can not find something useful.

Comment: If I'm identifying correctly, that looks like `volumeicon`. Does the command `pkill -x volumeicon` remove it (temporarily)?

Comment: @Score_Under `pkill -x volumeicon` does not work

Comment: Formulate your title to be a real question (start with capital letter, end with a "?").

Comment: Have you tried https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/124/volume-icon-remover/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is `pa-applet` package. I removed it and icon gone.